# node/express - missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

new to node...

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser= require('body-parser');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

module.exports = function PeopleController() {

function process(req, res, next) {
    var baseURL = '/people';

    app.get(baseURL + '/?', (req, res) => {
      console.log('people get');
    });

    app.post((baseURL + '/people', (req, res) => {
      console.log('people post');
    });
  }
}
```

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: `app.post((`  to `app.post(`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an unnecessary parenthesis in

```
app.post((baseURL + '/people', ...);
```

Replace that with

```
app.post(baseURL + '/people', ...);
```

or enclose the first parameter with a closing parenthesis.

```
app.post((baseURL + '/people'), ...);
```

Comment: Thank you!  I thought I'd checked over everything but I just knew another set of eyes would spot it.