# React js - nodemon: app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I just started using `nodemon` and strtaed creating a very small example project.
However, as soon as I launch the server `sudo npm run dev` I get the following error:

`[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`

The error says that there is a mistake on `users.js:7 app.use(expressLayouts);`

> emanuele@pc:~/Desktop/dashboard$ sudo npm run dev
>
> > dashboard@1.0.0 dev /home/emanuele/Desktop/dashboard
> >     nodemon app.js
>
> [nodemon] 2.0.2 [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs` [nodemon]
>   watching dir(s): *.* [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
>   [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
>   /home/emanuele/Desktop/dashboard/routes/users.js:7
>   app.use(expressLayouts); 
>   ^
>
> ReferenceError: app is not defined
>       at Object. (/home/emanuele/Desktop/dashboard/routes/users.js:7:1)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
>       at Object. (/home/emanuele/Desktop/dashboard/app.js:7:19)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10) [nodemon] app crashed -
>   waiting for file changes before starting...

So below is where the error should be:

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');

const app = express();

app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));
app.use('/users', require('./routes/users'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('welcome'));

module.exports = router;
```

**users.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Login Page
router.get('/login', (req, res) => res.send('Login'));

// Register Page
router.get('/register', (req, res) => res.send('Register'));

module.exports = router;
```

If needed below my `package.json`

```
{
    "name": "dashboard",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "app.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node app.js",
        "dev": "nodemon app.js"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
        "ejs": "^3.0.1",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "express-ejs-layouts": "^2.5.0",
        "express-session": "^1.17.0",
        "mongoose": "^5.8.11",
        "passport": "^0.4.1",
        "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
    }
}
```

I don't understand what is wrong in the above piece of code. 
I consulted some posts such as:

1) [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57446101/nodemon-app-crashed-waiting-for-file-changes-before-start) but could't solve the problem

2) [This one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42288361/node-express-missing-after-argument-list) but no success

3) I consulted [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51868233/nodemon-app-crashed-waiting-for-file-changes-before-starting)

4) I came across [this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57409705/nodemon-app-crashed-waiting-for-file-changes-before-starting-nodejs) but could still not figure out what could be wrong

Thanks for pointing in the right direction to understand where the error could be.

Comment: Can you show the code for `users.js`? That is where it says the error is.

Comment: Yeah, same issue in users.js as index.js -- you can't use `app` if it isn't defined.

Comment: **If** this is your exact code then this should work - your issue is somewhere else that you're not showing.

Comment: this is the exact code. After I rin `sudo npm run dev` I get the following error now: `Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000`

Comment: which is strange because I just closed and restarted `Visual Studio Code`

Comment: @Emanuele You don't need `sudo`, just do `npm run dev`, and the error you're getting right now basically says that there's an app already running on port `5000`, so you probably didn't close it correctly. Figure out the process ID of your node app by running `lsof -i :5000` and then kill it by running `kill -9 PROCESS_ID`, and try again. Also what happens if you just run `node app.js`? What's the error you're seeing then?

Comment: Do you think [this](https://i.imgur.com/L2kr3jP.png) could be helpful to understand what is happening?

Comment: @Emanuele you didn't kill that process, use `sudo kill -9 15764`

Comment: Ok thanks! server starts now! :) thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `index.js` (and `users.js`) there is no `app` variable defined:

```js
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

These should be defined in `app.js` where you have this definition `const app = express();`. They will then apply for all other routes in your Express application, so defining them multiple times is not needed.

Comment: thanks for reading the question. I just updated the code with the modifications but still does not work. I get the same error.

Comment: thanks that was the error. But also I had another silly error due to not correctly ending/starting the server which was resolved.